# Trim a text file via a batch file

Tags: string, batch-file

I want to trim a text file from both top and bottom.
Say if the text file contain 90 lines. I want to delete top x lines and bottom y lines and update the file. (ie leave only the range x+1 to y-1.
Hence I to intend write a batch file and run it as follow.

```
trimmer.bat file1.txt 2 8
```

This code below has following limitations
(a) file open/amend twice
(b) Trims blank lines within the range (I do not wish to remove these lines)

Please help me to correct

```
@echo off
rem %1% file name  %2%range begins   %3%range ends

rem Step1: this code trims the bottom section
set /a bot_trim=%3
echo Removing...
for /f "skip=%bot_trim% delims=*" %%a in (%1) do (
echo %%a >>newfile.txt
) >nul
echo Lines removed, rebuilding file...
xcopy newfile.txt %1 /y >nul
echo File rebuilt, removing temporary files
del newfile.txt /f /q >nul
echo file bottom trimmed...

rem Step2: this code trims the Top section
set /a Top_trim=%2-1
echo Removing...
for /f "skip=%Top_trim% delims=*" %%a in (%1) do (
echo %%a >>newfile.txt
) >nul
echo Lines removed, rebuilding file...
xcopy newfile.txt %1 /y >nul
echo File rebuilt, removing temporary files
del newfile.txt /f /q >nul
echo file bottom trimmed...
echo file trim completed !!
pause
```

contents of file1.txt

```
aa
ff
ff

dd
dd

ee
ee
ee
```

Comment: Why would `trimmer.bat file1.txt 2 8` delete the top 10 lines and bottom 15 lines? Are empty lines counted /preserved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR /f "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%a IN ('FIND /c /v "" %1') DO IF "%%c"=="" (SET /a endline=%%b-%3) ELSE (SET /a endline=%%c-%3)
ECHO %2 %endline%
(
FOR /f "tokens=1*delims=:" %%a IN ('findstr /n /r "^" %1') DO (
 IF %%a gtr %endline% GOTO done
 IF %%a gtr %2 ECHO(%%b
)
)>newfile.txt

:done

GOTO :EOF
```

Designed to suit your original specification. No attempt to cater for spaces and batch-significant symbols in file/directorynames, but directorynames may be used if required.

Lines beginning `:` will be damaged.

Produces newfile.txt

Comment: Thanks.It does the job what I originally asked. Now I realize my actual requirement is quite different. I want to save only the range specified. Say if a file has unknown number of lines(eg 100+). I wish to delete everything apart from the range specified(eg 20-44). Since I do not know the exact length of file, it is important to pass paramaters I want save to a new file.

Comment: In that case, you can remove the setting of `endline` (and the echoing thereof, which I omitted to delete) and replace `%endline%` in the remaining for-loop body with `%3`. Note that to refer to command-line parameters, use `%n`, not `%n%`. `%var%` is used for ordinary environment variables - not command-line parameters.

Comment: I fixed it. Further more replaced the %2 with set /a Top_trim=%2-1. So that It wont delete the line I want in range. What did u mean by "delete the echoing thereof"

Comment: `ECHO %2 %endline%` echoes the calculated value of `endline` (the last item that was referenced.) This line is of course not necessary - but I omitted to delete it. You have no need to calculate `top_trim` (and certainly no need to use CaMeL_cAsE since environment variables are case-insensitive.) You could simply change `%%a gtr %2` to `%%a geq %2` (greater-than becomes greater-than-or-equal-to.)  See `if /?` from the prompt for a full listing.